# slide the view controller to the left on a button click (not side menu)

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I am trying to build an app which requires two views on a single screen viz.day and night.I want to move the night view slightly to the left when I click a night button which is on the night view. I tried the side menu but it moves totally to the left and I want it to move slightly to the left like this:

[image]

Comment: which side menu you are used ?

Comment: Use https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController. Or any slide menu library to get your work done

Comment: @KKRocks I used MFSide menu, but it goes totally to the left,I want it to move slightly to the so that both the day and night menu will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `MFSideMenuContainerViewController's`  `leftMenuWidth` property .

```
container.leftMenuWidth = 50.0;
```

Comment: can you plz provide me your email ID so that I can show you my code

Comment: @user3969152 did you try this ?

Comment: -(IBAction)moonButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    _nightUIView.frame = CGRectMake(120, 00, (screenRect.size.width)/2, (screenRect.size.height -80)/2);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}this is working code for anyone having same issue :)

Comment: container.leftMenuWidth = 50.0; this code you need to set in appdelegate .

Comment: MFsideMenu provides default animation .

Comment: actually I faced  some issues while implementing MFSide menu, then I found this and it worked properly,But issue is that I am now able to move to left but not to right at its initial position.Any solution?? @KKRocks

Comment: - (IBAction)moonButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    _nightUIView.frame = CGRectMake(120, 00, (screenRect.size.width)/2, (screenRect.size.height -80)/2);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

Comment: this is for moving to left

Comment: why did you do this ? instead of its default function for open left menu.

Comment: it is working exactly what i wanted that why I used this .I did not able to implement left menu :(

Comment: in comment you have said me that you have used MFSideMenu so according to that i posted my answer .

Comment: this answer only for if you are use MFSideMenu library .

Comment: yes ,Right.But after that It was crashing and I did not able to resolve ,so i used this.